# Convert shell Script result into HTML table

Tags: html, shell, unix, scripting

Please help me to convert the result of shell Script into HTML table over email.
I wrote a shell script which will gives the output in below format.

```
Directory Name: /a/b/c
Business Date: 20200323
Expected_files_1:2
Expected_files_2:14
Actual_files_1: File count changes each day
Actual_files_2: File count changes each day
Comments of Actual_files_1
Comments of Actual_files_2
Other Comments
```

And I want to convert the above results into HTML table using shell script.

Expected HTML table:
[image: Output]

The table should always contains two rows, one is header and other is values of variables from script.
The first row is header of HTML table which will remain same always.
The second table values changes each day.

Since I am a beginner to HTML/Shell scripting I don't have any idea to write a script which will give me the result in above HTML format.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What specific problem(s) do you have with this task? Reading the input data? wrapping the data into HTML tags? Replacing characters that have a special meaning in HTML? Please [edit] your question to answer this. I also suggest to show example input for a few table rows and the expected output **matching the input**.  Your image shows a table with headings and one empty row. I guess this is not what you want.

Comment: I want a shell script to convert the results in HTML table format as per the image attached and send that table over mail.

Comment: Please add all information to the question. Does your file always contains the data for exactly one row in your expected HTML table? If yes, please state this in the question. If the table is expected to contain more than one row of data, please show an example for at least 2 rows. Please add questions about specific problems as I already suggested in my previous comment. (Someone already voted to close your question. This may happen very soon if you don't ask more specific questions.)

Comment: Thanks for replying back. Can you give me the command to convert above results into HTML table format?

Comment: @Rohith Shanbhag : Is their any header name available  for `Comments of Actual_files_1`  like how it is their for `Directory Name`  if that the case edit your input

Comment: @RohithShanbhag : does your work environment has python installed with Unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your output is stored in */tmp/output.txt* try this:

```sh
./yourscript.sh > /tmp/output.txt
awk -F ':' 'BEGIN { print "<html>\n<body>\n<table>\n\t<tr>" } { print "\t\t<th>"$1"</th>" } END { print "\t</tr>" }' /tmp/output.txt
awk -F ':' 'BEGIN { print "\t<tr>" } { print "\t\t<td>"$2"</td>" } END { print "\t</tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>" }' /tmp/output.txt
```

which returns

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
        <tr>
                <th>Directory Name</th>
                <th>Business Date</th>
                <th>Expected_files_1</th>
                <th>Expected_files_2</th>
                <th>Actual_files_1</th>
                <th>Actual_files_2</th>
                <th>Comments of Actual_files_1</th>
                <th>Comments of Actual_files_2</th>
                <th>Comments Other</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td> /a/b/c</td>
                <td> 20200323</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td> File count changes each day</td>
                <td> File count changes each day</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You'd make it easier for yourself if you made sure that every line output by your script had the same `key: value` format. We might help you further if you shared your script with us.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added my script now so can you plase help me get the result of above script in HTML table format over mail.

Comment: Can anybody help me to get the result in HTML table format from the above script?

Comment: @RohithShanbhag Could you upload a dummy input file to input into your script? I find it hard to decode what you're trying to do in a vacuum ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is a Two Step Process:

1. Transpose Columns into Rows, with colon as the input / output delimiter:

```
awk -f tst.awk inputfile.txt > result.txt
```

tst.awk contains the following code:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
{
    for (rowNr=1;rowNr<=NF;rowNr++) {
        cell[rowNr,NR] = $rowNr
    }
    maxRows = (NF > maxRows ? NF : maxRows)
    maxCols = NR
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1;rowNr<=maxRows;rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1;colNr<=maxCols;colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", cell[rowNr,colNr], (colNr < maxCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

2. for converting output of point 1 to html table format : There is an easy script available to do this at : https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/ which can be used to convert any command output or file to a nice html table format. You can specify the delimiter to this script, including special ones like tabs, newlines etc. and get the output in html table format with a html search at the top. Just download the script, extract it and issue the following command:

```
cat result.txt | { cat ; echo ; } | ./tabulate.sh -d ":" -t "My Report" -h "My Report" > output.html
```

Here : is taken as the delimiter.

I have attached a sample output.html here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/my-project-files/files/output.html/download